# add page after group in crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

i have a large crystal report (XI). the users want a completely blank page to print in between each group. they don't want the next group to just start on its own page... they want an entire blank sheet of paper in between each group. is there a way to do this? they are not using duplex printing.

the page is set up as

group1

```
    group2

    group footer2
```

group footer1

i need the blank page to appear after each instance of group footer 2

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- add a second group 2 footer section
- enable 'Force new page after' on both sections